# llvm-cov coverage missing when called from assertion

Tags: c++, llvm, code-coverage, llvm-clang, llvm-cov

I have the following header files:

power.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename R = decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<T>())>
constexpr inline R square(const T& x_) noexcept;
```

power.inl:

```
#pragma once

#include "power.hpp"

template <typename T, typename R>
constexpr inline R square(const T& x_) noexcept
{
    return (x_ * x_);
}
```

power_unit_test.cpp:

```
#include <power.inl>

int main()
{
    static_assert(square(2) == 4);
    assert(square(2) == 4);
    square(2);

    return (0);
}
```

After compiling with the flags `-fprofile-instr-generate` and `-fcoverage-mapping` in using clang++. And running the unit test binary, I get a report telling me that each of the three lines in main was called, but the function contents was only used once. This use is from the standalone call to `square(2)`, the asserts seem to not produce coverage reports correctly.

If I remove the standalone `square(2)` then the coverage does not reach 100%, as the asserts miss producing the coverage for some reason.

The coverage report reads as:

power.inl:

```
   22|       |        template <typename T, typename R>
   23|       |        constexpr inline R square(const T& x_) noexcept
   24|      0|        {
   25|      0|            return (x_ * x_);
   26|      0|        }
```

power_unit_test.cpp

```
   29|       |int main()
   30|      1|{
   31|      1|    static_assert(arc::math::sq(2) == 4);
   32|      1|    assert(arc::math::sq(2) == 4);
   33|      1|    // arc::math::sq(2);
   34|      1|
   35|      1|    return (0);
   36|      1|}
```

Please could you help me understand why the coverage is not being reported as I'd expect here? Is this a bug in llvm-cov or am I not understanding the coverage intent?

Compiling using homebrew's clang 7.0.1 on MacOS. Using CMake 3.13.2 for the build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that your compiler is inlining the `square()` function for both of the assert methods. Since the code is inlined, it never makes a call to your external code.

Your first thought might be to remove the `inline` identifier, but that wont work. This is because your compiler is most likely smart enough to recognize that the `square()` function *could* be inlined and goes ahead and does it anyway. The end result is that the external code does not get called.

So you need a way to bypass the inlining of the `square()` function. You can do this with a function pointer. See the following modification to your `main` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int (*f_ptr)(const int&);       // Ptr to func that takes 'const int&' and returns 'int' 
    f_ptr = &square;

    static_assert(square(2) == 4);  // Cant use 'f_ptr' here
    assert(f_ptr(2) == 4);
    f_ptr(2);

    return (0);
}
```

In the above code, we replace the explicit calls to `square(const int&)` with a pointer to the function, `f_ptr`. As a result, the compiler won't automatically inline the functions in the asserts and the code will be successfully called twice. The result:

power.cpp:

```
    4|       |template <typename T, typename R>
    5|       |constexpr inline R square(const T& x_) noexcept
    6|      2|{
    7|      2|    return (x_ * x_);
    8|      2|}
```

power_unit_test.cpp:

```
    5|       |int main()
    6|      1|{
    7|      1|    int (*f_ptr)(const int&);
    8|      1|    f_ptr = &square;
    9|      1|
   10|      1|    static_assert(square(2) == 4);
   11|      1|    assert(f_ptr(2) == 4);
   12|      1|    f_ptr(2);
   13|      1|
   14|      1|    return (0);
   15|      1|}
```

**A quick note**. Since `static_assert` is essentially a compile-time assert, we can't replace the call to `square()` with our function pointer, since function pointers are not [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). But don't worry, your compiler is smart enough to complain if you try to replace `square(2)` with the function pointer `f_ptr(2)` here.

Comment: Great explanation thanks! For anyone else who might find this useful passing -fno-inline to gcc may help. Clang seems to support the noinline attribute, but doesn't seem to have the same option as gcc.